# Display a chronometer, setInterval, in a primefaces datatable

Tags: javascript, primefaces, xhtml, setinterval

I just started on a Primefaces program. I want to display chronometer in a `Datatable`. I want to use `setInterval` for displaying a "real time chronometer". I got a Date object in the attribute `synopticBean.enteredTime` which I use for start counting.

But I don't know how to call a JavaScript function for displaying the chronometer.

```
<p:dataTable var="synopticBean" value="#{synopticLocationBean.synopticBeans}">
    <p:column headerText="Family">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.family}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="id">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.brNumber}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Target Time">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.referenceTime}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Δ">
        <h:outputText value="setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Elapsed Time">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.enteredTime}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The result I want it's a datatable where the two last columns display realtime chronometer that decrease and increase :

[image]

My datas are available with a java bean. The "Elapsed Time" column get a java Date like "Mon Jan 21 15:26:40 CET 2019". I don't know how to display a real time chronometer in each cell for the column. How can I set my java date to a `setInterval` method and display the "result" in a cell that I don't know the html's id?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back to jsf development or at least start with a more simple test without a datatable since `<h:outputText value="setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);" />` is already not right. You cannot put javascript in value attributes, they are for fixed strings or EL. And I'm not sure what you'd like to display there since the `setInterval` returns an id, not the interval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval and afaik, you cannot get the 'remaining' time before the next one fires

Comment: Effectively, you'd have the same problem in a plain jsf `h:datatable`  or with a single `h:outputText` so the question is not PrimeFaces (or xhtml) related...

Comment: Yes, the setInterval return the Id. I just want to display a chronometer in a cell of of the datatable. I want that chronometer is updating at each seconds. What do you mean by before the next one fires ?

Comment: The setInterval makes a javascript function executing at specific intervals. The 'remaining time before the next one fires' is the remaining time before the next time the function is executed (timers 'fire', a commonly used expression, sorry for not making that clear). This time is initial the full interval time but decreases to 0. If this is the time you want to have displayed, you can't (at least not very easily,  Javascript limitation, nothing JSF or PrimeFaces related). But you **can** start a an additional javascript countdown timer when you start the timer. Just google...

Comment: Not solved. I don't know how to display a counter. One of my problem is I don't have an 'id' for each cells so I don't know how to set the counter to each cells of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by @Kukeltje, I used the Primefaces extension, but I don't know how to start my counter by a value. I can have a date object or a millisecond as long type but I don't know how to use one of these two values can be the start value of my counter.

I add the following include to my JSF page :

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

and to my pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So the table :

```
<p:dataTable var="synopticBean" value="#{synopticLocationBean.synopticBeans}">
    <p:column headerText="Family">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.family}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="BT">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.brNumber}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Target time">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.referenceTime}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Δ">
        <pe:timer 
            style="color:grey;"
            forward="true" 
            format="HH:mm:ss"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Elapsed time">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.enteredTime}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert your above code into a working example you would do something like this,

```
<p:dataTable var="synopticBean" value="#{synopticLocationBean.synopticBeans}">
    <p:column headerText="Famille">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.family}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="BT">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.brNumber}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Temps cible">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.referenceTime}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Δ">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            setInterval(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 3000);
        //]]>
        </script>
        <!-- You can add any HTML code needed to display the chronometer here -->
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Temps Accumulé">
        <h:outputText value="#{synopticBean.enteredTime}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

As stated in the comments you don't use `h:outputText value` for this - that's intended for fetching a backing bean value.

Also note that this will call `setInterval` for each and every cell in the `Δ` column - which I guess is what you want. Just replace the `console.log` call with the call for updating your chronometer and it should work.

As as side note - it might be prefered to update all chronometers with just one `setInterval` call instead of having one for every cell in the `Δ` column. In the end it depends on what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: I got the impression that OP wants to actually disaplay a chronometer in each `Δ` cell. And normally a real javascript chronometer (or timer) (so not the basic javasscript  `setTimeout/setInterval` has starting/stopping built in. OP needs to be clear on this and investigate a little more. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timer/direction.jsf might be a full solution (Especially if OP also wants to fire something server side). These basics are more of the 'problem' of OP I think

Comment: Yes that is another route. Using the `p:poll` component already available in PrimeFaces could be another if somebody just wants to poll server-side data (like new values for the chronometers). As always, it depends on the requirements.

Comment: Kukeltje is right. I want to display a chronometer on each Δ cell. It will be a h:outputText value instead a cell of datatable. At this time I don't know how to display a chronometer, with a Date time start, and display the chronometer in the primefaces datatable.

Comment: If you want to display a chronometer in each cell, just insert the corresponding HTML / Javascript needed to display it directly under the `Δ` column above - just like the setInterval is being inserted. `h:outputText` is for outputting formatted text - you can't/shouldn't use it to output HTML/JavaScript that you want the browser to interpret.